# Flowplayer: Start playing video from specified time

Tags: flash, video-streaming, flowplayer, video-player

This question is specific to flowplayer video player (Flash Version) which I am using to play videos. Its a single video, not a playlist, I am referring to.

I am trying to setup to play video at particular time, say from 3 PM to 5PM.
If user opens my video linkat 3.30 PM, video should start playing after 30 minutes from beginning **but not from beginning of video.** Similar to a TV program scheduled.

I read somewhere as follows

> “You will always need to stream your videos (rtmp, pseudostreaming,
>   httpstreaming), because with progressive download starting from or
>   seeking to unbuffered positions is not possible.”

But youtube allows playing videos @ particular time! Example : http://youtu.be/JfAMCphCB1I?t=3m13s

How can I achieve to play video @ particular time? So far I didn't get any plugin or any parameter to seek and start from a specified position.

Appreciate kind support.

Note : [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174112/flowplayer-set-start-time-of-a-flv-video-from-amazon-s3?rq=1), not helping. This.seek is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to RTMP:

[According to this:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/devguide/WSeb6b7485f9649bf23d103e5512e08f3a338-8000.2.3.html) if you're not using RTMP, you can't. But Adobe is a bit biased, because they created RTMP.

> Delivering content over HTTP is usually called “progressive download”.
>   The content must transfer from the server to the client in a
>   progression from the beginning to the end of a file. A client cannot
>   seek to a forward location until that location and all the data before
>   it has downloaded.
>
> Delivering content over RTMP is called “streaming”. The client creates
>   a socket connection to the server (such as Adobe Media Server) over
>   which the content is sent in a continuous stream. **The client can seek
>   to any point in the content instantly**, regardless of how much data has
>   been transferred.